# Passing a byte array from C# into C++ com object with C++ filling array

Tags: c#, c++, .net, com, interop

I need to pass a byte array into a C++ com object from C#. C++ will then fill the buffer for C# to read.

c++ function definition

```
STDMETHODIMP CSampleGrabber::GetBuffer(byte* bd)
{
    int p=0;
    while (p< nBufSize) {
        bd[p]=pLocalBuf[p];
        p++;
    }
```

c# code :

```
byte[] byTemp = new byte[nBufSize];      
igb.GetBuffer(ref byTemp);
```

This crashes the program with no exception. Please can someone help. Thanks

SOLVED:

with

```
byte[] byTemp = new byte[nBufSize];

GCHandle h = GCHandle.Alloc(byTemp, GCHandleType.Pinned); 
igb.GetBuffer(h.AddrOfPinnedObject());
```

Thanks

Comment: These should be in completely separate projects.  The C++ code should be compiled as a library or DLL.  Once you've got them compiling separately, clarify your question, and we can help you integrate integrate the two parts.

Comment: If your as far as Jim has described, what is the interop signature for your `GetBuffer` method?

Comment: int GetBuffer(ref byte[] bd); is the interop signature. These are in two seperate projects what lead you to believe they werent ??

Comment: Solved: with byte[] `byTemp = new byte[nBufSize];

            GCHandle h = GCHandle.Alloc(byTemp, GCHandleType.Pinned); igb.GetBuffer(h.AddrOfPinnedObject());`

Answer (score 2):

The parameter should not be declared as `ref`.  You want something like:

```
uint GetBuffer(byte[] bd);
```

If you include the `ref` you are passing a pointer to the array, when you just want the array.  (And by array, I mean pointer to the first element.)

Comment: I assume you meant to say pointer to a pointer to an array?  (Leaving out "ref" will not pass the entire array by value!)

Comment: There is no "array" on the C++ side.  There's a chunk of memory, and a pointer to the first element.  (The data type of `bd` is `int*`, not `int[nBufSize]`)  Since array subscript notation can be used with pointers, it's easy to confuse the two.

Comment: I was thinking that when you pass an array in a C-style language it's implicit that you're really passing a pointer.  But I didn't express it very clearly.  I'll update the text.

Comment: Solved: with byte[] `byTemp = new byte[nBufSize];

            GCHandle h = GCHandle.Alloc(byTemp, GCHandleType.Pinned); igb.GetBuffer(h.AddrOfPinnedObject());`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but Google brought me here so it might bring someone else.
If you're using P/Invoke to call:

```
... GetBuffer(byte* bd)
```

it should look something along the lines of

```
[DllImport("MyDll.dll")]
... GetBuffer(ref byte bd);
```

And a buffer array in c# should be passed in like this:

```
var arr = new byte[Length];
GetBuffer(ref arr[0]);
```

This also works with `char*`, as you can just pass in the same `byte` array reference and then use `string s = Encoding.<encoding>.GetString(arr);`